# Upgrading to Entity Framework 6

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-6, partial-classes

I am upgrading from EF4 to EF6 and have problems of getting the model to work. I use VS2012.

First I didn't get any code generated which under EF4 worked automatically.
I changed EntityModel's Code Generation Strategy from None to Default and got classes generated.

But now my partial classes won't recognize any of the autogenerated class properties anymore.

```
Partial Public Class myObject
     '...
End Class
```

This class locates under the same Namespace as the autogenerated class. I didn't change anything in the partial classes.

For example when trying to access a navigation property from the partial class,
Visual Studio complains: `Error 16  'myObject_assumption' is not a member of 'MyNamespace.MyModel.myObject'`

Is there something in EF6 I need to do to make it work?

Comment: don't do the upgrade if you can wait a couple months, there's EF7 coming up

Comment: good to know. Unfortunately I can't wait that much here, need to stick with EF6

Comment: in that case - show us the generated code of myObject. Looks like DB-first? If so - take the table out and update from DB

Comment: Have you upgraded your Visual Studio EF tools([here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762))? Did you follow the instructions provided for upgrading from a previous version of EF to EF6 ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn469466))?

Comment: +1 for Visual Studio EF tools. I didn't have those. I also added EntityObject Generator (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ff479d55-2c85-43c5-a4d6-21cd659435ea).

Comment: But my Model.Designer.vb file stays empty, and saying: ' T4 code generation is enabled for model '....edmx'. 
' To enable legacy code generation, change the value of the 'Code Generation Strategy' designer
' property to 'Legacy ObjectContext'. This property is available in the Properties Window when the model
' is open in the designer.

Comment: ' If no context and entity classes have been generated, it may be because you created an empty model but
' have not yet chosen which version of Entity Framework to use. To generate a context class and entity
' classes for your model, open the model in the designer, right-click on the designer surface, and
' select 'Update Model from Database...', 'Generate Database from Model...', or 'Add Code Generation
' Item...'.